# AT+CSTT throws an error

Tags: programming, gsm

I am getting an error on

```
AT+CSTT="TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET","",""
```

What am I missing here?

**Code**

```
void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");
  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
  delay(3000);
  Serial.println("AT+CGATT=1");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET\"");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+CDNSCFG=\"4.4.4.4\",\"8.8.8.8\"");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CSTT=\"TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET\",\"\",\"\"");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIICR");
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIFSR");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSTATUS");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+CDNSORIP=1");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"www.google.com\",\"80\"");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSEND");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT");
}

void loop() {
  // run over and over
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

**Result**

```
AT+CGATT=1

OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET"

OK
AT+CDNSCFG="4.4.4.4","8.8.8.8"

OK
AT+CSTT="TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET","",""

ERROR
AT+CIICR

ERROR
AT+CIFSR

ERROR
AT+CIPSTATUS

OK

STATE: IP IND
AT+CDNSORIP=1

OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","www.google.com","80"

ERROR
AT+CIPSEND

ERROR
AT

OK
```

**Edit**

```
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is `mySerial` and what circuit it is connected to? Just a part of the code will not provide enough information to analyse your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**For others who reach here by search results**

Before this applying `AT+CSTT` command check if the modem is attached to GPRS using the `AT+CGATT=?` command. If the result is `+CGATT: 0` this means the modem is not attached so attach the modem using `AT+CGATT=1` command.

This will solve the issue as it was in my case. Even applying `AT+CIPCLOSE=0` and `AT+CIPSHUT` didn't help until I checked that that the result of `AT+CGATT=?` was returning `+CGATT: 0` and applied `AT+CGATT=1`.

Comment: `AT+CGATT?` , not `AT+CGATT=?`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late Siddharth,

try to get response of only `at+cstt=?`
Its return a exec  syntax and by following it you can make your frame of `at+cstt`

some below point may it will help

> //TCP connection profile AT+CSTT?
>
> +CSTT: "CMNET","",""
>
> OK APN->"CMNET"
>
> USER->""
>
> PASSWORD->""

and

> AT+CSTT="CMNET"
>
> OK
>
> at+cstt=?
>
> +CSTT: "APN","USER","PWD"
>
> OK

It may help you

regards

Comment: Have gone past that project long back. Will report back after I try. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AT+CSTT="TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET"`

Comment: tried, did not work\

Comment: What does `at+cstt=?` return?

Comment: Just a `ERROR`, as mentioned in the question above.

Comment: I mean what does the exact line `AT+CSTT=?` return? Also, what does `AT+CSTT?` return?

Comment: Sorry, AT+CSTT="TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET","",""

Comment: Ummm, what is the response to `AT+CGDCONT?` and `AT+CGACT?`. Could try adding `AT+CGACT=1,1` after `AT+CGDCONT=...`

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the problem is in low balance and account settings.
As I see, you doing all right.

```
AT+CGATT=1
AT+CSTT="TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET","",""
```

Also, check login/password! It's unusual to have blank credential here, in my country.